# Python pygame классы

Tags: python, классы, pygame

Благодарю если прочтете мой вопрос и сможете помочь с ответом. Я новичок в Python и соответственно у меня `проблемы с классами`.

Пишу небольшую игрушку на `pygame`. Ниже я покажу фрагмент кода которые не дают мне спать.

Я решил освоить наследование и создал родительский класс `Sprite`, от которого наследуются персонаж, его снаряды и метеориты. Я близок к завершению и **проблема заключается в отслеживании столкновений между вылетевшей пулей и двигающимся метеоритом**.

Как вы видите, я могу получить координаты летящей пули/метеорита, вернув координаты в методах `fly`/`fly_meteor`, у меня так же есть функция для высчитывания столкновения,(сейчас мои объекты удаляются из массива, только преодолев определенные координаты),

но я **не могу передать** из класса `Bullet` возврат значений метода `fly`(актуальные координаты в данный момент) в метод `destroy` класса `Meteor` и наоборот.

Я самоучка, не судите строго. Ниже представлен фрагмент кода

```
class Sprite:
    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos, imagePath, angle = 0):
        Sprite.last_id += 1
        self.id = Sprite.last_id

        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.angle = angle
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imagePath)

class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos, imagePath, angle = 0):
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.speed = 12

        super().__init__(x_pos, y_pos, imagePath, angle)

    def render(self, screen):
        self.fly()
        self.destroy()
        super().render(screen)

    def fly(self):
        ang = math.radians(self.angle)
        if 0 < self.angle < 90 or 90 < self.angle < 180 or -90 < self.angle < 0 or -180 < self.angle < -90:
            self.x_pos += self.speed * math.sin(ang)
            self.y_pos += self.speed * math.cos(ang)
        elif self.angle == 0 or self.angle == 180:
            self.y_pos += self.speed * math.cos(ang)
        elif self.angle == 90 or self.angle == -90:
            self.x_pos += self.speed * math.sin(ang)
        return self.x_pos, self.y_pos

    def destroy(self):
        if 850 < self.x_pos or self.x_pos < -850 or 650 < self.y_pos or self.y_pos < -650:
            GameController.destroy(self.id) 

class Meteor(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos, imagePath, angle = 0):
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.speed = 7

        super().__init__(x_pos, y_pos, imagePath, angle)

    def render(self, screen):
        self.fly_meteor()
        self.destroy()
        super().render(screen)

    def fly_meteor(self):
        self.y_pos += self.speed
        return self.x_pos, self.y_pos

    def destroy(self):
        if 850 < self.x_pos or self.x_pos < -850 or 650 < self.y_pos or self.y_pos < -650:
            GameController.destroy(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать функцию `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` для обнаружения столкновений.

Первые два аргумента - сами объекты, а третий (по умолчанию False) аргумент показывает, уничтожатся ли **оба** спрайта при коллизии.

Это удобнее чем высчитывать все самостоятельно, но оно не будет отслеживать столкновения попиксельно (только по прямоугольным хитбоксам).

Таким образом вы можете написать:

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(*bullet*, *meteor*):
    # Обработка
```

Если хотите могу дать официальную документацию pygame на английском: https://www.pygame.org/docs/

Comment: большое спасибо, я уже решил проблему

Comment: пожалуйста. я рад, что оказался кому-то полезен)